# Haskell - Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’

Tags: haskell

I just started learning Haskell. I have to write a function that does the following:

The definition of the function: `showCell :: Cell -> Char` (this was given)

If you call `showCell unknown` it should give back `'?'`, if you call `showCell empty` it should give back `' '` and if you call `showCell full` it should give back `'#'`.
I wrote this code:

```
showCell "unknown" = "?"
showCell "empty" = " "
showCell "full" = "#"
```

But I get a `Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’` error. What is the problem, and could you explain to me why?

Btw, the Cell type (in the definition of showCell) was also defined as: `type Cell = Char`

Comment: `"?"`, `" "`, and `"#"` are one character strings. You probably meant `'?'`, `' '`, and `'#'`.

Comment: @Alec I think that is an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :t "#"
"#" :: [Char]
```

`"#"` is a *character string*. The standard Haskell type for such strings is just *list of characters*:

```
Prelude> :i String
type String = [Char]    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

A *list* of things has a different type from the things themselves. Sure, there are lists which happen to contain exactly one element, but clearly it's not always appropriate to also allow any other number of elements (perhaps zero) when you *require* exactly one! Therefore Haskell always makes a type distinction between `a` and `[a]`.

So in this case you need `Char`, not `[Char]`. That's the difference between single-quote and double-quote literals:

```
Prelude> :t "#"
"#" :: [Char]
Prelude> :t '#'
'#' :: Char
```

Of course, this means that you can't put multiple characters in a single-quote literal, it's an error

```
Prelude> '#?*!^&&'

<interactive>:6:2: parse error on input ‘#?*!^&&’
```

...which is exactly what should happen, because it would violate the type signature if a function `-> Char` would sometimes give *multiple* characters as the result.

This also means that you can not possibly have `type Cell = Char`, because `"unknown"` is not a single character. I think what you really want is this:

```
data Cell = Unknown
          | Empty
          | Full

showCell :: Cell -> Char
showCell Unknown = '?'
showCell Empty = ' '
showCell Full = '#'
```